# NDSolve becomes very slow when the integration domain is 4 dimensional

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a PDE problem on a 4d manifold (3 space + 1 time). However, NDSolve becomes very slow when I jump from 3 to 4 dimensions. Here I want to integrate a simple `ndeps` dimensional diffusion equation on a `nindeps+1` dimensional manifold.

```
TimeNDSolve[nindeps_, ndeps_] := Module[
   {t, indeps, man, deps, \[CapitalOmega], BCs, ICs, eqs},
   man = Table[Symbol["$x" <> ToString@i], {i, nindeps}];
   indeps = {t}~Join~man;
   deps = Table[Symbol["$y" <> ToString@i], {i, nindeps}];
   \[CapitalOmega] = Cuboid@Table[0, {i, 1, Length@man}];
   BCs = {DirichletCondition[deps[[1]] @@ indeps == Sin[3 t], 
      indeps[[2]] == 0]};
   ICs = Flatten@Table[{q @@ (indeps /. t -> 0) == 0}, {q, deps}];
   eqs = Table[
     D[q @@ indeps, {t, 1}] == Laplacian[q @@ indeps, man], {q, 
      deps}]; AbsoluteTiming[
    nsol = NDSolve[{eqs, BCs, ICs} // Flatten, deps, 
      man \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, 1}]]];
```

For `nindeps =1` the program runs basically constant as `ndeps` is increased (Try `Table[TimeNDSolve[i, j][[1]], {i, 1, 1}, {j, 1, 100}]`). Timing says this takes $<1$ second per function call. If we increase to `nindeps =2` there is no significant slowdown.

However, if `nindeps` is increased to 3, suddenly the function takes ~170 seconds to run. I first thought that increasing dimensions would exponentially increase the number of simplices that any finite element solver would use to cover the base manifold, but this is more than exponential growth! It is absolutely ridiculous! I want to simulate a much more complicated PDE in this space which is currently unfeasible.

What is going on? Is there any way to speed things up? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's better to compare the number of degrees of freedom (DOF) for each dimension. (The DOF for a single PDE is roughly the number of coordinates in the mesh.) For that I have changed your code a bit:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(*ord=1;*)
ord = 2;

Ω = Cuboid@Table[0, {i, 1, 1}];
m[1] = ToElementMesh[Ω, "MeshOrder" -> ord(*,
   MaxCellMeasure\[Rule]0.00036*), MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0002];
Print[Length[m[1]["Coordinates"]]];

10001


Ω = Cuboid@Table[0, {i, 1, 2}];
m[2] = ToElementMesh[Ω, "MeshOrder" -> ord, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0003];
Print[Length[m[2]["Coordinates"]]];

10732

Ω = Cuboid@Table[0, {i, 1, 3}];
m[3] = ToElementMesh[Ω, "MeshOrder" -> ord, 
   "MeshElementType" -> 
    TetrahedronElement,(*MaxCellMeasure\[Rule]0.00022,*)
   MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00041];
Print[Length[m[3]["Coordinates"]]];

10849

TimeNDSolve[nindeps_, ndeps_] := 
  Module[{t, indeps, man, deps, Ω, BCs, ICs, eqs}, 
   man = Table[Symbol["$x" <> ToString@i], {i, nindeps}];
   indeps = {t}~Join~man;
   deps = Table[Symbol["$y" <> ToString@i], {i, nindeps}];
   Ω = Cuboid@Table[0, {i, 1, Length@man}];
   BCs = {DirichletCondition[deps[[1]] @@ indeps == Sin[3 t], 
      indeps[[2]] == 0]};
   ICs = Flatten@Table[{q @@ (indeps /. t -> 0) == 0}, {q, deps}];
   eqs = Table[
     D[q @@ indeps, {t, 1}] == Laplacian[q @@ indeps, man], {q, deps}];
   AbsoluteTiming[
    Monitor[nsol = 
      NDSolve[{eqs, BCs, ICs} // Flatten, deps, 
       man ∈ m[nindeps], {t, 0, 1}, 
       EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])],
     monitor]]];
```

These are then the timings I see:

```
Table[TimeNDSolve[i, 0][[1]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 1}]

{{0.342661}, {1.9421}, {8.83981}}
```

As for speeding things up in 3D, you might have success with reducing the accuracy/precision goal; something reducing the BDF order is helpful, though probably not in this case given here.

Comment: Your code works perfectly and I get the same timings that you do more or less. It may be blindingly obvious, but If you exchange `Length[m[i]["Coordinates"]]]` for `Dimensions[m[i]["Coordinates"]]]`, you get a `~{10000,i}` array that exactly explains the exponential growth of your timings, since we are really using exponenitally more points! Was my problem that Mathematica was decomposing my mesh strangely, making the use of `ToElementMesh` essential?

Comment: @Takoda, if you remove the options you will see that the default meshes generated do not match up for such a comparision in several ways: The element type is not comparable and the number of DOF generated is not comparable across the dimensions.

Comment: @Takoda, if I can ask you a favor, in your post could you replace the `ridiculous` with `unexpected`. Thanks.

Comment: @user21 `Cuboid@Table[0, {i, 1, 2}]` with option ` MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0003` has been meshed into  `TriangleElement["<" 81462 ">"` with length of 176261. It could be better to put  `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.003` for this case.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, I can not reproduce this.

Comment: @user21 I have tested this with v12.0.0.0, but with v12.1.1.0 there are `TriangleElement["<" 5277 ">"` and length of 10732. Is it bug o just some improvement?

Comment: @AlexTrounev, OK, I also see it in 12.0. Version 12.1 is an improvement as the boundary is not overly refined as it is in 12.0.

Comment: @user21 Is this means that we can't run FEM applications developed for v12.0.0.0  with v12.1.1.0 without testing?

Comment: @AlexTrounev no, it will run just fine, even better in this case as there are less elements in 12.1. This is a bug in 12.0 and fixed in 12.1

Comment: @user21 Your answers are excellent thank you very much! I have upvoted and selected this as the accepted answer. However, I do not see a reason to change the wording of my original post, and tend to avoid editing unless there is a gross miswording that creates a lack of clarity.